# Lemmatization of all pandas cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe.
There is one column, let's name it: 'col'
Each entry of this column is a list of words. ['word1', 'word2', etc.]

How can I efficiently compute the lemma of all of those words using the nltk library?

```
import nltk
nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('word')
```

I want to be able to find a lemma for all words of all cells in one column of a pandas dataset.

My data looks similar to:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[['walked','am','stressed','Fruit']],[['going','gone','walking','riding','running']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col'])
```

Comment: Use either `apply` or `applymap` based on your data. Better show us some data so we can suggest proper one

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `apply` from pandas with a function to lemmatize each words in the given string. Note that there are many ways to tokenize your text. You might have to remove symbols like `.` if you use whitespace tokenizer.

Below, I give an example on how to lemmatize a column of example dataframe.

```
import nltk

w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(text)]

df = pd.DataFrame(['this was cheesy', 'she likes these books', 'wow this is great'], columns=['text'])
df['text_lemmatized'] = df.text.apply(lemmatize_text)
```

Comment: Thanks ! But it tells me: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'text' ?

Comment: You have to give the name of the column that you want to apply the function! In my example, I create `text` as my example column.

Comment: It is normal that it take a long time ?

Comment: Your code works for your dataset. For my dataset, it tells me for the return statement: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I changed the "w_tokenizer.tokenize(text)" to text, since my entries are already single words (list of single words. But now it tells me: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: I changed the "w_tokenizer.tokenize(text)" to text, since my entries are already single words (list of single words. But now it tells me: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: I see my mistake. Some time I have some nan in the pandas cells! How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Just do `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` before applying the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
|col| 
['Sushi Bars', 'Restaurants']
['Burgers', 'Fast Food', 'Restaurants']

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
```

The below creates a function which takes list of words and returns list of lemmatized words. This should work.

```
def lemmatize(s):
'''For lemmatizing the word
'''
     s = [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in s]
     return s

dataset = dataset.assign(col_lemma = dataset.col.apply(lambda x: lemmatize(x))
```

Comment: It tells me: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'