# Lemmatization of pandas column using Wordnet after POS

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I have a pandas column `df_travail[line_text]` with text.

I want to lemmatize each word of this column.

First I Lowercase the text :

```
df_travail ['lowercase'] = df_travail['line_text'].str.lower()
```

Then, I tokenize it and apply POS (because of wordnet default configuration which consider every word as noun).

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
tok_and_tag = lambda x: pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))
df_travail ['tok_and_tag'] = df_travail['lowercase'].apply(tok_and_tag)
```

Then I have the following : (extract of the entire `df_travail['tok_and_tag']`

```
"[('so', 'RB'), ('you', 'PRP'), (""'ve"", 'VBP'), ('come', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('the', 'DT'), ('master', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('guidance', 'NN'), ('?', '.'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('this', 'DT'), ('what', 'WP'), ('you', 'PRP'), (""'re"", 'VBP'), ('saying', 'VBG'), (',', ','), ('grasshopper', 'NN'), ('?', '.')]"
[('actually', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('you', 'PRP'), ('called', 'VBD'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('here', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('but', 'CC'), ('yeah', 'UH'), ('.', '.')]
```

However, then, I'm lost about the lemmatization function to apply (with Wordnet), in order to take into account the fact that I applied POS ?

Edit : The following link doesnt mention POS part of my question
  [Lemmatization of all pandas cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557563/lemmatization-of-all-pandas-cells)

Comment: No, I know this post, no mentions about POS...

Comment: can you provide a sample data please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordnet lemmatization and pos tagging in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586721/wordnet-lemmatization-and-pos-tagging-in-python)

Comment: This specifically should help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335295/10140310)

Comment: Ok, then I understand that I have to change the classification in order to make it less specific and matching with the wordnet lematizer. However, how to mix everything with my pandas column ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to consider 'VERB' instead of 'NOUN' for lemmatization:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def convert(text):
    lemmatized_text = []
    for i in text.split():
        lemmatized_text.append(str(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(i,pos="v")))

    return ' '.join(lemmatized_text)

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: convert(x))
```